# php using special symbols

Tags: php

```
<?php do { ?>
     <?php echo "<a href=\"".$row_pageDetails['website']."\">"; ?><?php echo $row_pageDetails['name']; ?>(<?php echo $row_pageDetails['profile']; ?>)  </br> </a>  
<?php } while ($row_pageDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($rspageDetails)); ?>
```

This gives a clickable link  name(profile) but if the profile is empty It shows () how can I improve it so that when the profile record is empty it shows nothing.

Comment: What exactly is wrong? Please give us a contrete question.

Comment: Do you want the entire link to not show, or just to show something in its place?

Comment: Wow why are there so many `<?php ?>` tags? You can just: `<?php do { echo "something" . $something . "somethingelse" . something; } while (something);` (of course with proper indentation and line-breaking.

Answer (score 1):

You have many unnecessary opening and closing php tags. You should only use one for this whole thing given your code.

And you have a mis-closed `</br>` tag, should be `<br/>` and it would be better if you put it after the closing anchor tag.

You can not show the link at all by putting the whole thing in an `if` statement

```
<?php
     do {
       if(!empty($row_pageDetails['profile'])){
         echo "<a href=\"$row_pageDetails[website]\">";
         echo $row_pageDetails['name'] . "($row_pageDetails[profile])</a><br/>";
       }
     } while ($row_pageDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($rspageDetails));
?>
```

Comment: i get this   mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

Comment: @user1036077 Yes, `mysql_fetch_assoc()` needs to be passed a resource, which is usually the object returned from `mysql_query()`. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
(<?php echo $row_pageDetails['profile']; ?>)
```

use ternary operator

```
<?php echo ($row_pageDetails['profile']) ? '('.$row_pageDetails['profile'].')' : ''; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be something like this

```
<?php do {
 echo (isset($row_pageDetails['profile']) && !empty($row_pageDetails['profile']))? 
 '<a href="'.$row_pageDetails['website'].'">'.$row_pageDetails['name'].'('.$row_pageDetails['profile'].')</a>':''; } while ($row_pageDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($rspageDetails)); ?>
```