# conditional symbols in PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php using special symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071047/php-using-special-symbols)

```
(<?php echo $row_pageDetails['profile']; ?>)
```

If profile is empty it still shows this (). How can i get rid off () if profile is empty

Comment: Good question: Why it should _not_ show `(`, `)`? There is no condition anywhere, its not even within php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP's ternary operator and the shorthand syntax for output:

```
<?= ( isset( $row_pageDetails['profile']) && !empty( $row_pageDetails['profile'])) 
       ? ( '(' . $row_pageDetails['profile'] . ')' ) 
       : ''; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the parentheses inside of the php block.

```
<?php
 if(isset($row_pageDetails['profile'];))
  echo "(" . $row_pageDetails['profile']; . ")";
?>
```